# Kevin Luck's JQuery date picker plugin - render calendar in date interval and highlighting custom days

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a question about Kevin Luck's JQuery date picker plugin.

Is it possible to render calendar from 
selected date (for example from 01/01/1990 to 01/01/2015 ) ? 
And I want to highlight custom days (set css class .selected).
For example to select these days:

01/06/1990 |
09/02/1995 |
10/03/2005 |
11/01/2007 |
06/07/2010 |

I tried to write some code to achieve this, but still no good.

```
    $(function(){

        var testCallback = function($td,thisDate, year, month,day)
        {
            // some implementation here


            return true;
        }


        $('#calendar')
            .renderCalendar({renderCallback:testCallback})          
            .datePicker(
                {   
                    inline:true,
                    selectMultiple:false,
                    startDate:'01/01/1990'
                })              
            .bind(
            'dateSelected',
            function(e, selectedDate, $td)
            {
                date = selectedDate.asString();

                date = date.split(/\//);

                getStuffByAjax(date[2],date[1],date[0]);
            }
        );

});

function getStuffByAjax(year,month,day){
    // some implementation here

    return true;        
}
```

If I use renderCallback function I get rendered calendar with 
 only one month of the year.

Any ideas?

Would be appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question. So all I had to do is to put renderCallBack function
into datePicker method:

```
// JavaScript Document

$(function(){               
        $('#calendar')      
            .datePicker(
                {   
                    inline:true,
                    selectMultiple:false,
                    startDate:'01/01/1990',
                    renderCallback:function($td, thisDate, month, year)
                    {

                        if(thisDate.getDate() == 10){
                            $td.addClass('selected');   
                        }



                    }
                })              
            .bind(
            'dateSelected',
            function(e, selectedDate, $td)
            {
                date = selectedDate.asString();

                date = date.split(/\//);

                getStuffByAjax(date[2],date[1],date[0]);
            }
        );

});

function getStuffByAjax(year,month,day){
    // some implementation here

    return true;        
}
```

Now everything works as I wanted. Cheers.